# How to prove that this function $(x^2 + y^2) \exp{(\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2})}$ has limit?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have this multivariable function, and I need to prove that limit does exist and it's equal to zero.

$$(x^2 + y^2) \exp{\left(\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)}$$ for $(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)$

I've tried using polar coordinates method, and  I've got: $$\rho^2\exp{\frac{1}{\rho}}$$

then I write this inequality showing that: $$\left|(x^2 + y^2) \exp{\left(\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{\rho}\right|$$

but the right hand side diverges as $\rho \to 0$, and therefore i can't tell nothing about the left hand side.

---

I've tried using the restriction method, I've chosen: $(mx^n, 0)$ and I've obtained, $$m^2x^2x^n * \exp{\frac{0}{m^2x^2x^n}} = 0$$ but I can't say if the limit does exist, because restriction method tells me if the limit doesn't exist.

how can I do it?

---

EDIT (solved): there was an error in the polar coordinates substitution, there isn't $\frac{1}{\rho}$, instead I should've written $\rho^2*\exp{\left(\frac{\rho^2*(\cos * \sin)}{\rho^2}\right)}$ and the rest is straightforward, I've obtained $\rho^2*e$ which is the right hand side of the inequality, and it converges as expected.

Comment: You made an error when converting to polar. $xy/(x^2+y^2)$ does not become $1/\rho$ in polar coordinates.

Comment: $\frac{\rho*(cos*sin)}{\rho^2*(cos^2+sin^2)}$, but cos*sin is always <= 1, and cos^2+sin^2 is aways = 1. and therefore i can take the maximum (cos*sin becomes 1)

Comment: Your post is full of mistakes. It is not bad. It is this way one learns. Please correct them before we give you more hints (and don't read the answers, better find the solution by yourself). 1) $\exp\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\ne\exp\frac1\rho.$ 2) Your upper bound $\left|\frac1\rho\right|$ (where the absolute value is useless) seems to come from nowhere and is far too big. 3) The "restriction method" (where you made plenty of calculation errors) will anyway never prove what you want to prove (it is generally used to prove that there is *no* limit).

Comment: As for your last comment: you are on the right track but 1) you forgot a square on $\rho$ at the numerator 2) better edit your post (and correct it) than comment it.

Comment: Well! Can you please delete these 2 comments and edit your post?

Comment: I've edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the polar substitutions $x=r \cos \theta, y=r \sin \theta$, it becomes $$\left|r^2 e^{\left(\frac{r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{r^2}\right)}\right|=|r^2 e^{\sin \theta \cos \theta}|\leq |r^2|e.$$ The rest can follow, i.e., take limit $r\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: why did you write in the numerator of the exponent, $\rho^2$? shouldn't it be $\rho$?

Comment: Do you mean the $r^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$, like why is there an $r^2$? Previously it was $xy$, and so if we substitute $x = r \cos \theta, y=r \sin\theta$, we will get that form.

Comment: didn't you rewrite that this way: $\rho(cos*sin)$?

Comment: ah okay I've realized right now that it's completely wrong, thanks

Answer (score 3):

If $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, then$$-(x^2+y^2)\leqslant2xy\leqslant x^2+y^2,$$and therefore, if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$,$$-\frac12\leqslant\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant\frac12.$$It follows that the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\(x,y)&\mapsto&\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\end{array}$$is bounded, and that therefore your limit is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

$$(x-y)^2\ge 0 \implies xy \le \frac12(x^2+y^2)$$

then since $e^x$ is an increasing positive function

$$0\le (x^2 + y^2) e^{\left(\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\right)}\le (x^2+y^2)\sqrt e \to 0$$